# Read in integers from a file

Tags: java

The method is supposed to add all the integers on the line print out the result and then move onto the next line.

When I run the method it adds all of the integers except the last one on the line unless it has whitespace after it.  How can I make it add the integer regardless whether there is whitespace or not?

```
public static void addRows(String fileName) {
        int count = 0;
        int x;
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            s.useDelimiter("[ ]+");
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                    x = s.nextInt();
                    count += x;
                    }

                else {
                    System.out.println(count);
                    count = 0;
                    s.nextLine();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);

        }
        catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("No File Found.");}
}

Sample Input:
1  2   3
1 2 3

Output:
3
6
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add your sample file and expected output

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to do it by using the delimiter.

Try this piece of code. I have tested it for sample input. It works.

```
     public static void addRows(String fileName) 
    {
    int count = 0;
    int x;
    try 
     {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));


        while (s.hasNextLine()) 
        {
          String line = s.nextLine(); // get the next line
          Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner (line); // get a new scanner for the next line! Done! Now proceed the usual way.

            while (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) 
               {
                  x = lineScanner.nextInt();
                  count += x;
               }

            System.out.println(count);
            count = 0;

        }


     }
    catch(IOException e) 
     {
         System.out.println("No File Found.");
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String input;

while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  int sum = 0;
  String[] fields = input.split("\\s");
  for (String field : fields) {
    try {
      sum += Integer.parseInt(field);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // ignored
    }
  }

  System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: @sjr, the OP is using `count` as a sum, not a count of integer tokens.  I know it's confusing but the `count += ` in the code is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (true) {
            if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                count += s.nextInt();
            } else if (s.hasNext()) {
                next();
            } else if (s.hasNextLine()) {
                s.nextLine();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

should work regardless of how you define your delimiter pattern and whether or not line breaks are ignorable.

Comment: i tried that and put my print statement under s.nextLine() but it didn't print out after every line

Comment: There is no next line after the last line, and unless you have changed the delimiter to not match newlines, then the `hasNext()` will match a line break as well.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a lookahead to register a fake delimiter at the end of the line without actually consuming the \n:

```
s.useDelimiter("[ ]+|(?=\\n)");
```

Comment: He is probably using the Windows platform.
s.useDelimiter("[ ]+|(?=\r\n)"); does the trick. But tell me Russell, how does it work?